# NMEA GPS data from mobile hotspot -> Wifi-only iPad

Tags: ipad, gps, geolocation

I have a [4G mobile hotspot](http://www.verizonwireless.com/verizon-jetpack-mifi-4620l.shtml) for when I travel on business. It makes NMEA GPS data available to connected clients.

I've been thinking about buying an iPad (first one for me). Can the wifi-only iPad use this data? For the apps that I plan to use, GPS location is desirable.

I'm trying to figure out whether I need to shell out the extra dollars for a 4G model, or purchase a Dual or Bad Elf...

Comment: Hi. I am wondering what mechanism is employed for sharing of GPS data between mobile hotspot and clients. What make and model is the hotspot?

Comment: The particular device that I'm currently using is the Verizon (Novatel) Jetpack 4G LTE Mobile Hotspot 4620L.  Per its spec, it can provide an NMEA GPS signal over a virtual comm port.  As I don't currently own an iPad, I don't know if this is something that can be configured on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *most likely* out of luck here. Essentially, you can not install any drivers on the iPad, and the [handbook](http://cache.vzw.com/multimedia/mim/vzw_mifi_4620_jetpack/4620_manual.pdf) states on page 69 that...

> Drivers are needed to use either the "USB tethered mode" or "GPS over
>   Wi-Fi" features.

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/2123/26522) mentions a *jailbreak* for iOS to use a bluetooth connection to pass GPS data into an non-3G iPad, but your hotspot does USB and WiFi only — and I personally would not advise to jailbreak for [certain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1462/what-is-the-chance-that-jailbreaking-my-iphone-will-brick-the-phone) [reasons](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30952/what-are-the-risks-of-jailbreaking-an-ios-device).

The most promising approach to your question is this: If you do own/have access to an **iPhone**, you could try to **tether** the two via [Personal Hotspot](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4517). The iPad might get the location from the phone — as described in [this article](http://blog.urbanape.com/post/3798485232/show-me-the-way). Let me know how this works.